# Need Linux script to find specific file and see if specific content exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need some help with Linux bash script that needs to do following

- search for curl config file (.curlrc)
- if found check if it contains specific entry (curl -k) and report accordingly

Output should look similar to below (this is just sample)
/var/tmp/.curlrc | curl -k | FOUND
/var/opt/.curlrc | curl | NOT FOUND

I'v run following command that returns all the file(s) that exist in different folders

```
[root@server1 /]# find / -iname '*curlrc*'
```

/var/tmp/.curlrc
/var/opt/.curlrc

When running following command from /var/tmp directory

```
[root@server1 tmp]# find / -iname '*curlrc*' | grep 'curl -k' .* 2>/dev/null
```

.curlrc:curl -k

If I try to run command from the root '/' does not find anything

```
[root@server1 tmp]# find / -iname '*curlrc*' | grep 'curl -k' .* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: You always search for a file from the root (/) directory with find in all of your commands. This may take large amount of time if your system has lots of file installed. If you wanna start searching only from the working directory change the find command from `find /` to `find .`

Comment: Your existing code is grepping the _names_ of files, not the _content_ of those files.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following one-liner with `find` and `grep`:

```bash
find . -type f -regex ".*\.curlrc" -print0 | xargs -0 grep --with-filename --line-number --no-messages --color --ignore-case "curl -k"
```

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with this code, but any particular reason to use `-print0 | xargs -0 grep ...` instead of `-exec grep ... {} +`?

Comment: (the thing that _is_ wrong here is about the decision to answer an obviously-duplicative question; see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before")

Comment: Simply did not know about `-exec` of `find` and yes it is shorter, readable. Thanks for hint I will note `How to Answer` in future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using `-iname '*curlrc*'` if you are looking for files called `.curlrc`.

When you pipe `find` output (a list of filenames) into `grep`, that will be what grep searches, not the contents of those files.

When you pipe a list of filenames into `grep` and also provide a list of filenames (`.*`), `grep` will not read anything from its stdin. Consider:

```
echo hello | ( grep world /dev/null; cat )
```

---

One possible solution is to use `find`'s builtin `-exec` option to invoke `grep`, then print messages depending its exit status:

```
q='curl -k'

find / -name .curlrc \(                        \
    -exec grep -q -- "$q" {} \;                \
    -exec printf "%s | $q | FOUND\n" {} \;     \
    -o                                         \
    -exec printf "%s | $q | NOT FOUND\n" {} \; \
\)
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite for recursive grep-operations like yours is `grep --recursive`.
Change to the directory you want to search in and there

```
grep --recursive --include ".curlrc" "curl -k"
```

(The parameter `--include` takes a glob-style search pattern of file names, so with `--include "*curlrc*"` you can include all files with "curlrc" anywhere in their name in your search. Ignoring case of file names may be easier to achieve with `find . -iname ...`, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of finding files and checking its contents is:

```
find /dir -name "filename" -exec grep "content" {} /dev/null \;
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'find' command finds all the files with name '.curlrc' under the root directory, the grep command then finds for the existence of the desired string within each file.

```
for / file in `find -name .curlrc `; do
   grep -q "curl -k" $file
   if [ $? -eq  0 ]; then
      echo "'curl -k' found in file \"$file\""
   else
      echo "'curl -k' not found in file \"$file\""
   fi
done
```

You may also add '-maxdepth' option to 'find' command to restrict the search area.

Comment: See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on the BashFAQ and [why not parse ls (and what to do instead)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). `for file in $(find)` is brittle because of word splitting, there are better alternatives.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.